# Windows 10 Fall creators update - v 1709 - No optional features listed

Tags: openssh, windows-10-v1709

I'm trying to install the new OpenSSH client that ships with this version of windows 10 and is an optional feature.

To access the optional features, I click the start button, then search for "Manage optional features" and then click the "Add a feature" button.

The problem is, there are no features listed for installation - just a "No features to install" message.

What do I need to do to to be able to install? I have tried googling this but no one seems to have an answer. I definitely have the correct version of windows 10 (1709).

Comment: What features do you want to enable?

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking my answer isn't correct either. OP noted he's trying to enable the new OpenSSH client, referenced here: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/heres-how-to-enable-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-client/ This article states it is enabled through the method OP attempted.

Comment: @Nick, is your computer joined to a domain?

Comment: @music2myear no its just a stand alone pc at home. cheers

Comment: Have you enabled Developer Mode yet? Settings > Search for "developer" and select "Use Developer Features". Click "Developer Mode" and allow the changes to be made.

Answer (score 5):

The Optional Features panel is for things like Languages and keyboards. Microsoft does not appear to have completed rolling all of the legacy management utilities into the new Metro Settings application.

What you want is Windows Features, which is still found embedded in the old Programs and Features dialog.

You can get to this by opening **Settings** > **Apps** > **Apps and Features**, scroll to the bottom and under Related Settings click **Programs and Features**. When the Programs and Features dialog opens, click **Turn Windows features on or off**.

You'll now see the classic dialog where you should be able to select from the available features.

**UPDATE**

For the OpenSSH client, installation is done through the Optional Features dialog OP attempted to use. There are several reasons why no items are visible in this list:

- If the computer is a member of a domain that receives updates via WSUS, you may not see any features available to install (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23090805-2035-4439-8f11-2a6e84e53c0c/add-optional-features-when-domain-joined?forum=win10itprosetup)
- You may need to Clean Boot in order to install Optional Features (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/no-features-to-install-under-optional-features/83d8268a-26c5-4008-911a-ded2ecc30537)
- If you are connected to a Metered internet connection you may not be able to install Optional Features (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/trouble-installing-optional-features-from-settings/27f2debd-be69-465a-af63-72a7fe3e1294)

Comment: Additionally it appears this is as of a specific build of 1709.  If the feature isn’t listed then they have not installed the required update that was released this week on Tuesday: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054517 also developer mode will be required due to it being a beta feature

Comment: I'll test those factors @Ramhound and improve my answer.

Comment: The OpenSSH features are strange.  The articles are coming out this week talking about it but it’s been there since .15 which was the original patch build back in September.  So it’s likely connected solely to Developer Mode.  Strange more attention by Microsoft to this feature hasn’t happen

Comment: I tested on an Insider Preview VM that's not domain joined (no dice, nothing listed in the Add Optional Features and Developer options are on), and on a domain computer, which gave an error noting it couldn't reach Windows Update (patching is via SCCM to that makes sense). OP solved it with a couple reboots, apparently though.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Version 1803 which I *thought* was supposed to come with OpenSSH. However, OpenSSH client is still not installed and I have no idea how to install or where to get it. Anyone?

Comment: If the feature does not show up under Optional Features, how does one install it?  I gave up and ended up downloading it from Win32-OpenSSH project on GitHub.  See my solution here: https://superuser.com/a/1348200/384322

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, i restarted the computer then checked and the list was still empty. I restarted again and can now see optional items including the OpenSSH !

Hope this helps someone else.

Thanks all for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I realize this doesn't answer the question of, "why are no optional features listed?", but if you need OpenSSH Client, [here's what worked for me](https://superuser.com/a/1348488/384322).

I had a similar issue where I could not install OpenSSH Client because it didn't appear under Optional Features (after I updated to Windows version 1803.)

I ended up downloading and installing OpenSSH Client directly from the [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) project on GitHub by following these awesome instructions by Matt McElreath:

http://blog.techsnips.io/openssh-windows-setup/

Although Matt's TechSnips article was helpful and includes an [easy to follow video](https://www.techsnips.io/en/how-to-set-up-openssh-on-windows), it's recommended to look at the installation instructions provided on the Microsoft [Win32-OpenSSH project Wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki), which change periodically:

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH

Here's a summary of the steps from Matt's blog linked above:

1. Download the latest release of [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)
2. Unpack the ZIP archive into `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH`.
3. Add `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\OpenSSH-Win64` to the Windows System PATH. (Instructions for modifying system PATH on Windows [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/).)

If you also want to use OpenSSH Server (`sshd.exe`) and OpenSSH Authentication Agent (`ssh-agent.exe`), there are additional steps which are needed to install and enable these as Windows Services.  These steps are more involved and I suggest you follow the instructions from the [Win32-OpenSSH Wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) or from [Matt's article directly](http://blog.techsnips.io/openssh-windows-setup/).

Comment: Instead of just linking to an answer, please edit your answer and describe what helped you.