# (after installed openssh) 'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

Checked in `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin`, there is no ssh.exe, just only these files:

```
ssh-add.exe
ssh-agent.exe
ssh-host-config
ssh-keygen.exe
ssh-keyscan.exe
```

[image: openssh not work]

Comment: How was it installed?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot which shows that OpenSSH Client is installed.  [The information I am looking for is within the Settings application not Windows Features.](https://superuser.com/questions/1348064/windows-10-v1803-where-is-openssh-client/1348864#1348864).  **You are also looking in the wrong directory by the way.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 v1803: where is OpenSSH Client?](https://superuser.com/questions/1348064/windows-10-v1803-where-is-openssh-client)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I installed OpenSSH using https://just-install.it/

Comment: @Ramhound : I've check your guide, it doesn't work for me, but I've found this guide and problem got solved: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

Comment: @Ramhound the command `Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'` return error, maybe there some proble with my windows 10 installation, but when i follow the guide in winscp.net to download and manual install, it works

Comment: @Luke - The command in my answer absolutely work.  You failed to identify which version of Windows 10 you are running.  You downloaded a standalone OpenSSH client, you didn't install the OpenSSH Client, built into Windows.  Of course, there isn't a huge difference.