# Open SSH is not in Window optional features

Tags: windows-10, openssh

I just uninstalled OpenSSH server and client on my Window 10 (version 1803). However, there is none of them in the optional feature list. When I first installed OpenSSH, they were still there. Is there a way to fix this or to get SSH without using optional features?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Edit your question, and provide the relevant information from `winver`, this information is necessary to answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 v1803: where is OpenSSH Client?](https://superuser.com/questions/1348064/windows-10-v1803-where-is-openssh-client)

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find that duplicate question. Besides, I updated my Windows and they were in optional features again.

Answer (score 2):

Please see if the features can be installed using DISM /Add-Capability. Open PowerShell or CMD as administrator and run the following commands

```
 DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
 DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Comment: Where can I find list of capabilities available for my OS? I'm curious what else is there.

Comment: @Kamil `Dism.exe /online /Get-Capabilities`

Comment: What would cause /Get-Capabilities to not show openssh.server?  Server 2016, v1607.