# Windows 10, sshd.exe missing

Tags: windows-10, ssh, sshd

According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview), OpenSSH is now part of Windows. The executable files are in `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`, and indeed I could see them on my system. However, `sshd.exe` is not there. Does anyone know why? Do I have to install something special to get `sshd.exe`?

My `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` contains only the following items:

```
    Directory: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          19/03/2019    06:21         322560 scp.exe
-a---          19/03/2019    06:21         390144 sftp.exe
-a---          19/03/2019    06:21         882688 ssh.exe
-a---          19/03/2019    06:21         491520 ssh-add.exe
-a---          19/03/2019    06:21         384512 ssh-agent.exe
-a---          19/03/2019    06:21         637952 ssh-keygen.exe
-a---          19/03/2019    06:21         530432 ssh-keyscan.exe
```

Comment: I don't think it comes pre installed, because my win-10 pc does not have it either. a quick google search could probably help you download it

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse shows how to install on windows server

Comment: @FredTheDoggy - What makes you think the author is using Windows Server instead of Windows 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> According to this, OpenSSH is now part of Windows.

The `OpenSSH Client` and `OpenSSH Server` are both optional Windows Features. Only the `OpenSSH Client` is installed by default.  Based on the contents of the installation directory you do indeed have the `OpenSSH Client` installed.

> However, sshd.exe is not there. Does anyone know why?

`sshd.exe` is the actual OpenSSH Server daemon.  You do not currently have the OpenSSH Server installed[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1348064/windows-10-v1803-where-is-openssh-client/1348864#1348864)

> Do I have to install something special to get sshd.exe?

Yes;  You need to install the `OpenSSH Server`.  `OpenSSH Server` is available as an Optional Feature on `Windows 10 version 1803+`. To install `OpenSSH Server`, from Manage optional features -> Add a feature, select `OpenSSH Server` to install:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check if SSH server already installed:

```
powershell.exe "Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH.Server*'"
```

If not, install it:

```
PowerShell.exe Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

both commands need admin rights