# What is the "SSH" equivalent for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I recently had to start managing remote Windows 10 systems (non-servers) and am curious if there is an SSH equivalent for running command prompt commands remotely.

Is there a default utility for doing this?

Comment: [OpenSSH](https://superuser.com/questions/1348064/windows-10-v1803-where-is-openssh-client/1348864#1348864) is built-into Windows 10 (through an optional feature).  So the Windows equivalent to SSH is SSH.  The optional windows feature is the Windows port of OpenSSH (with a few improvement from Microsoft).  [Microsoft is the primary contributor to the OpenSSH Windows port.](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable)

Comment: The following article talking about how to enable SSH on windows 10:https://ittutorials.net/microsoft/windows-10/enable-ssh-windows-10-command-prompt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments mention windows builds of SSH, but the actual equivalent for managing windows systems from windows is [Powershell sessions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pssessions?view=powershell-7.1). Here's a few good starting points:

`Enable-PSRemoting`: Configures a PC to accept PS Sessions: Opens a firewall port, verifies the service is running, etc.

`Enter-PSSession` is the equivalent to a normal `ssh` command. It connects to the remote machine, starts a Powershell prompt, and streams it back to your terminal:

```
Enter-PSSession Win10PC
# Equivalent to 
ssh MyUsername@Win10PC

# Prompt will look like this to show you're in the remote PC:
[Win10PC]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

`Invoke-Command` uses the same remote session process, but just runs the command you give it and sends you the result (better for scripts):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Win10PC -ScriptBlock {Get-PSDrive}
```

Like SSH, Powershell will use the current user to connect to the remote machine, and run as admin if possible. To run as a different user, add the `-Credential` flag

```
Enter-PSSession Win10PC -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

This doesn't require that you be in a windows domain, but it will work a lot better if you are.

Comment: I only mentioned OpenSSH, due to the other's asking for an SSH equivalent on Windows, which of course is OpenSSH.

Comment: [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6)